# How to reset state values to default after a condition in REACT?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am building a simple find a carrot game with React JS.

**How this game should work**

1. Click the start button to play
2. Carrots and bugs will spawn to the field (default count is 10). If the carrot is clicked, it will be removed, and if I click a bug, I lose the game.
3. Timer starts when game starts

**What I am trying to do**

If I click a bug, click the stop button, or I can't find all carrots within the duration of time, I want my states to reset to the default. Is there any better way to structure functions like startGame, stopGame?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/carrot-game-3e7dc?file=/src/app.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Update code

https://codesandbox.io/s/carrot-game-forked-64cbw?file=/src/app.jsx

`in react data flows unidimensional`

We need to let the `app.jsx` know that a `bug` click happened and reset accordingly.

on **field.jsx**

`resetGame` is defined on `app.jsx`

```
if (e.target.dataset.item === "bug") {
      // On bug click
      resetGame();  // 
      setBugs([]);
      setCarrots([]);
    }
```

in **App.jsx**

if the timer is up then inside `useEffect`

```
if (sec <= 0) {
      setShowPopUp(true);
      setMessage(`Your score ${score}`);
    }
```

on `refresh` icon click inside `popup`

```
 const reStartGame = () => {
    setShowPopUp(() => false);
    stopGame();
  };
```

**Note** : explore state management like `redux` or react [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting.
In this game app like this, which kind of states should I use with react context?

Comment: context work in this, if you have plans to make it even more big then go with redux for maintainability

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea to use state management for your app state if your app gets bigger.
For this example, I use a Provider to be my state management:

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
const DURATION = 5;
const initialState = {
  start: false,
  score: 0,
  sec: 0,
  reset: () => {},
  startGame: () => {},
  stopGame: () => {},
  handleScore: () => {}
};
export const gameContext = createContext(initialState);

function GameProvider(props) {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
  const [sec, setSec] = useState(DURATION);
  let timer;

  const startGame = () => {
    setStart(true);
  };

  const stopGame = () => {
    setStart(false);
    clearTimeout(timer);
  };

  const handleScore = () => {
    setScore(score + 1);
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setStart(false);
    setScore(0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (start && sec > 0) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setSec((sec) => sec - 1);
        console.log(sec);
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [start, sec]);

  return (
    <gameContext.Provider
      value={{ start, score, reset, startGame, stopGame, handleScore }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </gameContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default GameProvider;
```

And when you want to reset, remember to also clear all the carrots and bugs

```
reset()
setBugs([]);
setCarrots([]);
```

Working codesanbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/carrot-game-forked-3pxqz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark